# Enabling multi-touch on a non-multi-touch touchpad

Tags: multi-touch, trackpad

I have Ubuntu 13.04 on my HP Pavilion G4-1025TX, which I don't think has multi-touch (it didn't have multi-touch when I was on the bundled Windows 7). Is it possible to enable multi-touch for this machine on Ubuntu?

Comment: The HP [Product Specifications](http://bizsupport1.austin.hp.com/bizsupport/TechSupport/Document.jsp?objectID=c02748351&lang=en&cc=us&taskId=101&prodSeriesId=5046252&prodTypeId=321957) says your touchpad supports multi-touch. Go to "System Settings" -> "Mouse & Touchpad" and check "Two finger scroll". Try to scroll a page moving two fingers up and down.

Comment: Thank you very much, I didn't know my touchpad is multi-touch!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you download the Synaptics TouchPad driver from the Ubuntu Software Centre (search for synaptiks).

This worked well for me. You have to auto start it by putting it in the Start Up Programmes with `synaptikscfg init`. Apart from that it's simple and straight forward.